# Sistemas distribuídos (vantagens e desvantagens)

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, sistema-operacional, sistemas-distribuídos

Quais são as vantagens e desvantagens de um sistema distribuído?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As maiores vantagens:

- Escalabilidade - você pode "facilmente" crescer a capacidade de atendimento adicionando novos nós de execução, e isso faz atender demandas grandes no prazo estabelecido.

  Ao contrário do que as pessoas acham, não fica mais rápido. Você ter mais caminhões transportando uma carga não entrega a carga mais rapidamente, apenas entrega mais carga no mesmo prazo. Na verdade costuma haver custo adicional de processamento e chega ser até ligeiramente mais lento por ter que administrar tanta coisa.
- Resiliência - se um nó tiver problemas os outros continuam operando e o sistema como um todo não para.

Todas as outras vantagens são derivadas destas ou não possuem muita importância.

Principais desvantagens:

- Complexidade - este é um dos problemas mais difíceis de resolver em toda computação, coordenar tudo é complicado, custa caro em todos os sentidos e a chance de algo dar errado no processo é grande. Aqui incluo problemas de segurança que aparecem, ainda que não sejam insolúveis, apenas são complexos.
- Desperdício - é comum usar muito mais recursos para operar nesta modalidade já que há um custo de coordenação.

Também há desvantagens derivadas destas ou eventuais.

Depende:

- Custo - há casos que o custo pode ser menor usando um ou outro. O que muita gente não percebe é que o que parece barato pode se tornar caro. Há situações muito específicas que não fazer distribuído fica inviável, e essa é a boa notícia. O problema vem quando parece que dá para fazer sem distribuição, e aí o hardware custará muito caro, ou mesmo o software tem que ser feito em termos muito detalhados com muita otimização e isto pode ser absurdamente caro.

O contrário parece ser mais frequente. As pessoas optam pelo distribuído por conta das vantagens, e nem se importam com o custo, ele custará mais caro, mas a pessoa acha que precisa de qualquer forma. Acontece que raríssimos problemas realmente precisam da distribuição, pelo menos a distribuição real, aquela que precisa de coordenação e não apenas parcelamento simples de carga de trabalho absolutamente independentes (isto não é distribuição).

Algumas pessoas podem achar que não precisa ser complexo, e é verdade, se você abrir mão da confiabilidade, segurança e outras características que são normalmente necessárias. Onde dá para abrir mão parcialmente pode ficar mais simples. Por isso quem mais usa distribuição tem características no seu problema que são simples demais ou podem abrir mão de algumas dessas coisas. O problema é quando a pessoa tem algo para resolver que não é assim mas ela acha que a distribuição é boa para seu caso, e ela nem se dá conta do rolo onde está se metendo.

Estou falando da distribuição tradicional com vários computadores, mas mais ou menos vale para qualquer tipo de distribuição.

É mais ou menos a mesma coisa de ter uma pessoa ou uma equipe trabalhando em um projeto. Pensa em termos de pessoas. Qual você escolhe? Quando decide mudar para a outra forma?

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, vai me ajudar muito.

Comment: @Maniero: Nesse conceito de distribuição e escalabilidade pode-se empregar metodologias como Agile e DevOps?

Comment: @AugustoVasques Sim, não vejo porque não. Alguns diriam que só pode ser assim :) Claro que é exagero, mas distribuição precisa automatizar muito, ter um controle formal e DevOps pode ajudar bem na operação. Agile não sei, até sim, mas de forma ortogonal. Sei lá, Agile pra mim é algo tão mais simples do que as pessoas dizem por aí, é algo tão simples que nem precisa pensar muito sobre, você apenas faz.